# How to get points for uploading pictures to show problem better?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to show my problem and use the upload picture tool but the website warn me that need 5 points.But I don't have points and didn't find how to get points though I trid to seach the method how to get points.
Is anyone can give me some advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322881/how-to-get-points-for-uploading-pictures-to-show-problem-better?/) by [Andong Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/41359/andong-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2019-05-09

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-05-10**:
Now you have more than 5 points.

**Comment by [Fanon](https://answers.ros.org/users/126002/fanon/) on 2023-01-25**:
I had the same issue. Thanks for posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the FAQ.   https://answers.ros.org/faq/

> How does karma system work?
>
> When a question or answer is upvoted, the user who posted them will gain some points, which are called "karma points". These points serve as a rough measure of the community trust to him/her. Various moderation tasks are gradually assigned to the users based on those points.
>
> For example, if you ask an interesting question or give a helpful answer, your input will be upvoted. On the other hand if the answer is misleading - it will be downvoted. Each vote in favor will generate 10 points, each vote against will subtract 10 points. There is a limit of 200 points that can be accumulated for a question or answer per day. The table below explains reputation point requirements for each type of moderation task.

```
1   upvote
3   post a link
1   add comments
50  downvote
25  accept own answer to own questions
25  open and close own questions
100 retag other's questions
75  edit community wiki questions
1000    edit any answer
200 delete any comment
```

---

Originally posted by [Tyrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/40650/tyrel/) with karma: 141 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-10**:
So the summary would be: answer another question (gives you 15 points) or get one of your own questions answered.

**Comment by [Andong Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/41359/andong-chen/) on 2019-05-10**:
thank you very much

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-10**:
@Andong Chen: please accept the answer by @jayess by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

**Comment by [Shravista](https://answers.ros.org/users/60779/shravista/) on 2020-10-11**:
thank you for providing the information

**Comment by [rcbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/80739/rcbot/) on 2021-08-11**:
thank you for info:)

**Comment by [aforlano22](https://answers.ros.org/users/108811/aforlano22/) on 2022-06-22**:
Thank you for this information

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try using google docs links

---

Originally posted by [Fanon](https://answers.ros.org/users/126002/fanon/) with karma: 21 on 2023-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2